# How to get form values in asp.net mvc from properties not directly in the model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a form which will have some standard properties based on the model, but the user will be able to extend those properties.

So I have an Entity called Entity, another entity called Property, and another Entity called Company.  An Entity can have a list of properties (like twitter handle, website, etc). However I want to save the values of those extended properties in an XML field on the company entity.

To illustrate I will paste the model here.

```
  public class Entidad
        {
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Nombre { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<Propiedad> Propiedades { get; set; }
        }

public class Propiedad
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual Entidad Entidad { get; set; }

        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string TipoDeDatos { get; set; }
    }

 public class Empresa 
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string NIT { get; set; }
        public string NombreRepresentanteLegal { get; set; }
        public string TelefonoRepresentanteLegal { get; set; }
        public string NombreContacto { get; set; }
        public string TelefonoContacto { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "xml")]
        public string PropiedadesExtra { get; set; }

    }
```

On my create view I have the following:

```
@model Inspinia_MVC5.Areas.GlobalAdmin.Models.Empresa
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Areas/GlobalAdmin/Views/Shared/_LayoutGlobalAdmin.cshtml";
    var propiedades = (List<Inspinia_MVC5.Areas.GlobalAdmin.Models.Propiedad>)ViewData["CamposAdicionales"];
}
```

and I render the custom attributes like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">Propiedades adicionales</div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    @foreach (Inspinia_MVC5.Areas.GlobalAdmin.Models.Propiedad propiedad in propiedades)
                                    {
                                        if (propiedad.TipoDeDatos == "Texto")
                                        {
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.Label(propiedad.Nombre, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                                @*@Html.LabelFor(prop => propiedad.Nombre, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
                                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                                    @Html.Editor(propiedad.Nombre)
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(prop => propiedad.Nombre)
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        }
                                    }

                                </div>
                            </div>
```

On the empresas controller Create action I have this:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var listFields = from b in db.Propiedades
                                             where b.Entidad.Nombre == "Empresa"
                                             select b;

            ViewData["CamposAdicionales"] = listFields.ToList<Propiedad>();

            return View();
        }
```

And this renders a nice form like this:
http://screencast.com/t/7HsI6ci9GVdo

However, what I dont know, is how to take those dynamic form fields and take those values to save them in the XML field from the Empresa(company) entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the page is rendered, click on view-source, and see the name of the input field that you created, it should be the value in each propiedad.Nombre ,  On server side you can access  this field's  value by `Request["fieldname"]`,
so for each item, get's it's value by

```
Request[propiedad.Nombre]
```